# How to include many locales while checking .isAlpha with validator.js

Tags: node.js, validation, express, express-validator

Working on an express.js app, I validate (server side) inputs using the Express-validator middleware. On a specific input, which must contain only Greek or English letters, I try this `isAlpha(['el-GR', 'en-US'])` as validator.js library recommends.

However, while testing this, I get this error:

> Invalid locale 'el-GR,en-US'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) library that express-validator uses, you can only specify one locale.

> Locale is one of ...

What you can do is create a custom validator that loops over all the characters in the string and check whether it's an alpha in the correct locale. E.g.

```
const { validator } = require('express-validator');
const { check } = require('express-validator/check');

module.exports.add = [
    check('title').custom(value => {
      for(let charIdx = 0; charIdx < value.length; charIdx += 1) {
          if (!validator.isAlpha(value[charIdx], 'en-US')
           && !validator.isAlpha(value[charIdx], 'el-GR')) {
            throw new Error('Illegal title'); 
          }   
      }

      return true;
    })
];
```

add is the validator chain function.

I haven't tested all edge cases, but at first glance it looked ok on my machine.

Comment: It works, although I solved my problem using regex. Anyway, your answer seems more elegant to me.